# Remote Attestation TPM Protocol

Tags: security, tpm

I try to create a protocol to remote attestate my agents. I deploye for example 3 agents. These 3 agents something decide to migrate, so i need to attestate the location that the agent decide.

Every agent have a TPM module, so everyone have a key pair, and a certificate emited by the CAm but i dont know how to do the protocol without the figure of a CA because this was a requisite.
Anyone can help me?